# Reversed Linked List: Why does the position of head = head.next matter?

Tags: python, linked-list

Can anyone explain why the position of this line `head=head.next` must be right after `curr=head` and not any further down? Initially, I was putting `head=head.next` in the last line of the while loop but was getting only the last node. Eg. If the input was `[1,2,3]`, I would get `[1]` using the second block of code and `[3,2,1]` with the first.

Correct:

```
def reverseListIterative(head: ListNode):
    prev = None
    while head:
        curr = head
        head = head.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
    return prev
```

Wrong:

```
def reverseListIterative(head: ListNode):
    prev = None
    while head:
        curr = head
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        head = head.next
    return prev
```

Comment: At the time of the assignment to `head`, `curr` and `head` are the same.  So the assignment `curr.next = prev` changes the *original* `head.next`, i.e. the one used in the assignment `head = head.next`.  So obviously, doing that assignment before the assignment to `head` would change it.

Comment: Note that `curr is head` at that point. So any mutation on `curr` (like `curr.next = prev`) would affect `head`, too, if you did not not reassign it first.

Comment: With something like this, it helps to draw a diagram showing what things point to.  It's not a language issue at all, but is really just an exercise in reasoning something out by carefully analyzing it.

Comment: @TomKarzes and user2390182 Thanks! Understand what happened now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could figure this out by tracking the content of each variable through the code flow (you don't even need to run it):

Let's say we start with the list 1 -> 2 -> 3

```
                          prev  curr head  head.next  curr.next
                          ----  ---- ----  ---------  --------- 
prev = None               None  -    1     2          -
while head:
    curr = head           None  1    1     2          2  
    curr.next = prev      None  1    1     None       None      *** 
    prev = curr           1     1    1     None       None 
    head = head.next      1     1    None  -          None    
return prev
```

When you assign prev (None) to curr.next, you lose the connection from head.next because head is also pointing to node #1.